# Insert documents to MongoDB when count is equal to expected value?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to insert/upsert multiple documents in MongoDB 4.2 only if the the number of documents matching a particular query is of a particular size?

Example:

Let's say I have an `items` collection with the following 2 documents:

```
{ item: "ZZZ137", type="type1"}
{ item: "ZZZ138", type="type1"}
```

Now I want to insert these two documents:

```
{ item: "ZZZ139", type="type1"}
{ item: "ZZZ140", type="type1"}
```

but *only* of there are currently 2 items of type `type1` in the collection (i.e. count of `type1` is equal to 2).

Is it possible to somehow do this in MongoDB with a single command?

**Update**

To further illustrate my question let's imagine that [insertMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) had support for conditions. Then I'd like to do something like this (pseudo code that doesn't work):

```
db.items.insertMany({ { $count: { type: "type" } } : { $eq : 2 } } , [{ item: "ZZZ139", type="type1"}, { item: "ZZZ140", type="type1"}])
```

Where `{ { $count: { type: "type" } } : { $eq : 2 } }` would be the query that must be fulfilled in order to insert item `ZZZ139` and `ZZZ140`.

Comment: Not getting what you mean here. Could you please elaborate it more like what is the issue with a simple insert? Also, how are you currently doing this with multiple commands?

Comment: Added a pseudo code example

Comment: There are no conditional inserts in Mongo, you'll have to split it into 2 calls.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert then that would answer my question, so maybe you want to add it as an answer? My hope was that this would be possible with an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: What Mongo version are you on? it is possible to use `$merge` or `$out` to do so but I would not recommend using the `$out` option as it's very inefficient.

Comment: I'm using MongoDB 4.2 (4.2.6 to be precise).

Comment: I added an answer with all the options, i still recommend splitting it into 2 calls as it is the most "sane" option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) or [`$merge`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#pipe._S_merge) if you insist on doing this in 1 call, however it's very inefficient due to the logic and restriction of these 2 operators. I personally recommend splitting it into 2 calls:

```
let typeTwoCount = await db.collection.countDocuments({type: "2"})
if (typeTwoCount === 2) {
   await db.collection.insertMany(newItems)
}
```

Now we can use `$out` but due to the fact that it re-writes the collection we'll have to carry the entire collection through the pipeline and into the `$out` stage, which is ridiculous:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            typeTwo: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        type: "2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    $count: "doc_count"
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        newDocs: {
                            $cond: [
                                {$eq: ["$doc_count", 2]},
                                items,
                                []
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $unwind: "$newDocs"
                },
                {
                    $replaceRoot: {
                        newRoot: "$newDocs"
                    }
                },
            ],
            all: [
                {
                    $match: {}
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            merged: { $concatArrays: ["$all", "$typeTwo"]}
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$merged"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$merged"
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "collection"
    }
])
```

Now the issue with `$merge` is the following restriction:

> The output collection cannot be the same collection as the collection being aggregated.

So we can employ similar tactic to the `$out` pipeline (with using the `typeTwo` pipeline for the `$merge`), but we'll have to start the aggregation with a different none empty dummy collection:

```
db.any_other_none_empty_collection.aggregate([
    {
        $limit: 1
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "collection",
            let: {},
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        type: "2"
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "all"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            doc_count: {$size: "$all"}
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            newDocs: {
                $cond: [
                    {$eq: ["$doc_count", 2]},
                    items,
                    []
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$newDocs"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$newDocs"
        }
    },
    {
        $merge: {
            into: "collection"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: If split into 2, would that be synchronisation issue? if 2 user request at the same time

Comment: If you have a concurrency issue then you need to handle this racing condition in code, as it can occur even if you use a single pipeline as only the `$merge` stage is atomic on it's own.

Comment: Did you mean sleep the request with promise ?

Comment: I mean that if there is a race condition and you're using an aggregation pipeline with `$merge` then you should ensure only 1 request is executed at a time at the application level.

Comment: There is only one possible which is sleep mutex, non-clustered nodejs is single thread unless reach to `promise state`. Just lock with sleep mutex and release on finally stage.